# InfoPath Form in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I have used several infopath forms with great success in Sharepoint.

I am running into a strange problem on one form I'm working on right now.

Basically, I have a status report form. One of the fields is asking whether a project is Green, Yellow, or Red.

What I want is for this selection to appear in a column in sharepoint, but not as text, as an image.

To do this, I created a column in the form SharePoint library called Status. I used the hyperlink/picture column for this. And yes, I did turn on "display url as image" for that column.. I then created a rule in InfoPath which took the result from my form field, and set another field's value (in this case, set the sharepoint status column field to a url link to a green indicator i want to have displayed). As an example, if you open my form and tel me your project is GREEN, the rule should write "http://www.schooldashboard.org/tths205/images/IndicatorGreen.png" to the status column in SharePoint for that file.

However, no matter what i do, nothing gets written to this column from InfoPath. My hunch is that there is a data connection or something missing to submit that specific field value to sharepoint but I can't figure out how to do that.

I also tried actually hosting the indicator image on my sharepoint server to see if it was being blocked somehow, but that didn't change anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that the field in InfoPath is bound to the field in SharePoint. I run into that all the time.

Comment: Robert, can you elaborate. I believe this is set up? What I did originally was set up a data connection to receive from SharePoint so that it allowed me to select the fields I had created on the sharepoint side. see here: the column in sharepoint i am trying to have it send to is "status". http://postimg.org/image/nv9lpi8a1/

Comment: this is what the rule looks like: http://postimg.org/image/da08rdkp5/

Comment: How are you writing the the data back to SharePoint?  The data connection appears to only be a select.

Comment: I have a Main Submit Data connection http://postimg.org/image/7ek0g301p/